# dynamic background with map and tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to map on an array and use the urls inside the array with the tailwindcss code as the background of the div tag, but the existing image is not applied to the background.
Apparently, tailwind cannot read the photos in the map

this is my code :

```
function Home() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-[700px]">
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={30}
          slidesPerView={3}
          onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
          onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
          className="w-full"
        >
          {films &&
            films.map((item) => {
              return (
                <SwiperSlide key={item.id}>
                  <div
                    className={`w-[200px] h-[300px] text-white bg-[url('${item.diskImage }')]`}
                  >
                    <span className="z-100 relative bottom-1 left-2">
                      {item.title}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </SwiperSlide>
              )
            })} 
</Swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not build the class names dynamically in Tailwind: [Don't construct class names dynamically](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).

So if that image is used many times throughout your application, define the class name (or a set of class names) in the `tailwind.config.js`,
and use these in your components, e.g.:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: {
                myBg: 'url(/public/bg.png)',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

```
<div className={'w-[200px] h-[300px] text-white bg-myBg'}>
```

If the images are very specific to that item, you don't need a "class" anyway,
and could just use the `style` attribute, e.g.:

```
<div
    className={'w-[200px] h-[300px] text-white'}
    style={{ background: `url(${ item.diskImage })` }}
>
```