# Can Tailwind sibling (peer) state work on React dynamic lists?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to follow the official Tailwind CSS documentation, building the examples on the side in a React (Vite) environment.

In the [differentiating peers example](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#differentiating-peers), I'm not able to have the hidden text to reveal, whatever radio button is checked.

I suspect that's because the radio inputs are generated at run time, and so, Tailwind can't generate the needed CSS at compilation time. Can you confirm it, and eventually propose an alternative solutions?

Here's my React component:

```
export default function RadioGroup({ formId, legend, name, fields }) {
    return (<fieldset className="mx-auto max-w-md bg-white p-8 text-sm shadow">
        <div className="mb-6 border-b border-slate-200 pb-2 text-base font-semibold">
            {legend}
        </div>
        {fields.map((field) => (<>
            <input 
                key={`field-${field.id}-input`}
                id={`${formId}-${field.id}`}
                className={`peer/${field.id} mr-2 mb-0.5 border-slate-300 text-sky-400 focus:ring-sky-300"`}
                type="radio"
                name={name}
            />
            <label 
                key={`field-${field.id}-label`}
                htmlFor={`${formId}-${field.id}`}
                className={`peer-checked/${field.id}:text-sky-500 font-medium`}
            >
                {field.label}
            </label>
        </>))}
        {fields.map(field => (<div 
            key={`description-${field.id}`} 
            className={`peer-checked/${field.id}:block hidden mt-4 text-gray-500`}
        >
            {field.description}
        </div>))}
    </fieldset>)
}
```

Here's the generated HTML:

```html
<fieldset class="mx-auto max-w-md bg-white p-8 text-sm shadow">
  <div class="mb-6 border-b border-slate-200 pb-2 text-base font-semibold">Published status</div
  
  <input id=":rb:-draft" class="peer/draft mr-2 mb-0.5 border-slate-300 text-sky-400 focus:ring-sky-300&quot;" type="radio" name="status">
  <label for=":rb:-draft" class="peer-checked/draft:text-sky-500 font-medium">Draft</label>
  
  <input id=":rb:-published" class="peer/published mr-2 mb-0.5 border-slate-300 text-sky-400 focus:ring-sky-300&quot;" type="radio" name="status">
  <label for=":rb:-published" class="peer-checked/published:text-sky-500 font-medium">Published</label>
  
  <div class="peer-checked/draft:block hidden mt-4 text-gray-500">Draft are only visible to administrators.</div>
  <div class="peer-checked/published:block hidden mt-4 text-gray-500">Your post will be publicly visible on your site.</div>
</fieldset>
```

I've tried both controlled and uncontrolled component, to no avail.

Thank you very much for your time.

EDIT: Reading the docs (as pointed out by @kca in the accepted answer), I am able to put a workaround. Thankfully, Tailwind can find class names anywhere in my JS(X) files, so I am able to build a finite list of class names and using those based on the index in my fields list:

```js
const peers = [
    'peer/radio-0',
    'peer/radio-1',
    'peer/radio-2',
    'peer/radio-3',
    'peer/radio-4',
    'peer/radio-5',
    'peer/radio-6',
    'peer/radio-7',
    'peer/radio-8',
    'peer/radio-9',
]

const peersChecked = [
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-0:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-0:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-1:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-1:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-2:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-2:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-3:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-3:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-4:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-4:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-5:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-5:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-6:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-6:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-7:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-7:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-8:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-8:block' },
    { text: 'peer-checked/radio-9:text-sky-500', block: 'peer-checked/radio-9:block' },
]
```

Example usage:

```
 {fields.map((field, index) => (<div key={`description-${field.id}`} className={`${peersChecked[index].block} hidden mt-4 text-gray-500`}>{field.description}</div>))}
```

While this works, this makes me create an arbitrary numbers of classes that might be more or less than needed in the current situation. So, while I consider the issue solved, I'm still open to better workaround, or even a clean solution!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, you [can not build the class names dynamically in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).

Use pre-defined class names, if it's only a fixed set of alternatives,
or add styles instead of class names, if all the elements are very specific.

See also the answer to *["dynamic background with map and tailwindcss"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75922560/7556457)*.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the correct part of the docs. What I did not expect is that Tailwind is able to find classes anywhere in my JS, which help find a workaround for this (see my edited question).

Comment: Yes, I was surprised myself. I believe you could even put the class names in comments, because Tailwind [just inspects the code for text matches](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths) :) _(But, of course, the way you did it is surely better.)_.